# Как открыть файл с++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Как открыть любой файл?(именно открыть а не прочитать, что бы пользователь выдел его открытие)

---

Мне нужно открыть файл txt который НЕ находится в одной папке с проектом. Можете подробно написать как это делать?

Comment: Открытие файла незаметно для пользователя. Вы явно хотите не открыть файл, а что-то еще. А вот что - не ясно. Дополняйте вопрос.

Comment: `system(файл)` может?

Comment: Если вам нужен WinAPI OpenFileDialog, то попробуйте [GetOpenFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы открыть файл txt который НЕ находится в одной папке с проектом, в имени файла нужно указать полный путь к этому файлу. Либо есть второй вариант - сменить текущую директорию и открыть файл без полного пути, но после этого настоятельно рекомендуется обратно вернуть текущую директорию. :-)

UPD1:

И еще - полный путь можно указывать или абсолютный, или относительно текущей директории. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
ShellExecute(0, 0, "notepad.exe", полный_путь_и_имя, 0, SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: @0xdb, почему не содержится?

Comment: @Qwertiy Согласен, слишком короток, чтобы сразу понять, надо было пропустить.